# Android: Is there a way to have an image fill the screen without stretching or cropping it

Tags: android, xml

I'm using `android:scaleType="centercrop"` or `android:scaleType="center"`

It more or less ruins the image

I'm using Android Studio if that makes any difference.

Comment: `centercrop` maintains the aspect ratio. What do you mean by *It more or less ruins the image*?

Comment: without crop any image can't fit, if not designed for the specific design

Comment: Sorry, when I use centercrop or center it ruins the image by stretching it and zooming in. I get why it does this, I'm new to android studio and was just wondering if there is another way to fill the screen but keep the image as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want `centerInside`, which has the following behavior --

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that
>   both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or
>   less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

For more details, see the [`ScaleType` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Comment: Thanks mate, I appreciate the help.